# Visa required for a 1 week holiday/conference in NYC

Tags: visas, usa

I am an Indian student studying in Paris. I would like to attend a conference in NYC on July 13-18th, with the trip lasting for a total of one week.

What type of US visa should I apply for and how long would processing take?

Comment: Have you looked at US Embassy's site in Paris? http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/visit/visitor.html

Comment: @Karlson: In particular, there is a "wait time estimate" on that site, which estimates a 23-day wait for an interview, plus an additional 3 days of processing time.  It seems unlikely that you can get it done before July 13.

Answer (score 4):

Since noone else did I will put this in an answer.

As the [US Embassy in Paris](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/visit/visitor.html) page for visitor's visas states you will need a B-1 visa to attend a conference.

On the same page you can put in the city where you will have your interview and it will tell you what is the current waiting time.